# Can Dts.TaskResult be omitted in script task in SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis

for the C# code written in `script task` in SSIS below, can `Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;` be omitted? Because no matter it is reachable or if it is commented out, task will still success in executing. Is it default to `Success`? It looks a boring question, just curious :)

```
    public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here

        int a = 0;

        if (a == 1)
        {

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
         //or comment out "Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;" outside the "if"  will still let the script run successfully

    }
```